# why the program doesn't call the js class function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, oop, events

I have a class in JS, that contains a series of methods inside, related with a login and user's register. These methods basically catching the page's events and they do something.

When it's created the instance for UsersOperations(), and it's called (due to click event) `$("#login").click(function(){});`, is executed correctly... until before calling the `saveUserInfo();`, in this point, the page is reload, and i don't know why, i don't understand, i had the same methods but without class and all worked fine.

Please, help me, or else, i'll die with this existential problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  new UserOperations();
});

  class UserOperations{
    constructor() {
      if(!this.checkUserWithLogin())
        this.addLoginAndRegisterButtons();
      var self = this;
      $("#Log_In").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "php/request.php",
          async: true,
          data: {nick_log:$("#username").val(),
                  pass_log:$("#userpass").val()},
          success: function(data){
          var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);

          if(dataJson==null)
            alert("You are not registered");
          else {
            if($("#Keep_log").is(':checked')) 
              self.saveUserInfo(dataJson,"localStorage"); 

            else 
              self.saveUserInfo(dataJson,"sessionStorage"); 
            self.checkUserWithLogin();
          },
          error: function (obj, error, objError){
            alert("There is an error!");
          }
        });
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Most likely because that `#login` button submits a form?

Comment: But in that case, the ajax function would not receive the data (because it receives the data from request.php effectively) or not?
And no, the button "#login" isn't submit type. But it's in a form tag

Comment: How do you know that the `success` function is called at all? How do you know it executes "until that point" before the page is reloaded?

Comment: Because i put some `alerts` in success...Many `alerts`, and the messages were shown up until that point

Comment: Well, that likely means that an exception was thrown at that point. Did you look at your error console? (This wouldn't explain why the page reloads, though)

Comment: Yes i saw the console and there was no error. Maybe i don't see it because the page is reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `this` isn't referring to the object anymore so it can't find the function. The function you attach as a callback doesn't close over `this`. You can either use another variable like `var self = this;` or you can bind your callback using Function.prototype.bind().

Here's some example code to make the answer more complete, showing three different mechanisms to preserve the context.  The root need for these approaches is that when creating a callback function, we don't automatically preserve the value of `this` that exists within the method that defined the callback function.  We need some mechanism to execute the function on the proper object:

```
function Cat(name) {
    this.name = name;

    // Note we don't need anything special when we're immediately executing:
    console.log("Immediate execution with this:");
    this.speak();

    // Option 1. Explicitly specify the value of 'this' inside the callback using bind()
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Callback execution with bind:");
        this.speak();
    }.bind(this), 1000);

    // Option 2. Copy 'this' into a local variable which is then captured in a closure
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Callback execution with closure variable:");
        self.speak();
    }, 2000);

    // Option 3. (ES6) Use a lambda/arrow function which does preserve the value of 'this' from the context in which it was defined
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Lambda preserves the value of this:");
        this.speak();
    }, 3000);

}

Cat.prototype.speak = function () {
    console.log(this.name + " says meow!");
}
```

Comment: If is so, why `this.addLoginAndRegisterButtons()` runs correctly?. It's so strange, i also tried to take out the `this.`, and happens the same.

Comment: Because on that first line, you're still in the constructor, not in a callback. The constructor has the right context, but when you create an anonymous function which is used as a callback, that function will not have that context. I'm at lunch & on a cell phone right now - when I get home I'll add more code to explain this better.

Comment: oooooh, i understand now, you have all the reason. It was that i had not  consider the context. I changed the code, and now works...Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Spines - Glad it's working!  Added some more example code to have a more complete answer, showing a few ways to solve this problem.